# Show only posts of my friends on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I've liked many pages on Facebook and now my news feed is dominated by their posts. I like going through it, but sometimes I just want to see friends' posts.
**Is there a way to filter all posts except my friends'?**

Comment: switching from **Top Stories** to **Most Recent** is not what i'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

I have also liked many pages on Facebook and would like a way to just see my friends' posts.  The only way to do this is to create a custom list:

1. Click on the FRIENDS section on the left sidebar.
2. Click on the "+ Create List" button at the top of the screen.
3. In the box that appears, enter a list name and then click the "Create" button.  It will show the list you created with "No posts to show".
4. Click on the "Add Friends to List" button.
5. Click on all of your friends so that each person has a checkmark on their photo, and click the "Finish" button.
6. Reload the list by clicking on it under the FRIENDS section on the left sidebar, and it will show you only the posts from your friends.

The only issue with this solution is that whenever you add a new friend, you have to remember to add that person to the list you created.  You can add a new friend to the list by clicking on the "Manage List" button on the upper right of the list page and selecting "Edit List", and then change "On This List" to "Friends", and then you can select your new friend.

Comment: That's indeed what I do, I'm still in hope there's another solution...